# ROS3djs set URDF color not working

Tags: ros, urdf, ros3djs, collada, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I've built my own robot in solidworks, so I have the 3D .dae parts. I also have the URDF model working on the web browser by the package ros3djs (http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs/Tutorials/VisualizingAURDF). The problem is that when it displays the model on the web browser, each link gets a random color. I have set the color on the .dae file and also on the URDF file, but it's not working, every link keeps getting a random color.
I get the following errors on the webconsole:

```
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create roslib.min.js:1:7936

THREE.WebGLRenderer 61 three.min.js:1:285997

Error: WebGL: getExtension('MOZ_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc'): MOZ_ prefixed WebGL extension strings are deprecated. Support for them will be removed in the future. Use unprefixed extension strings. To get draft extensions, set the webgl.enable-draft-extensions preference. three.min.js:1:285144

THREE.WebGLRenderer: Anisotropic texture filtering not supported. three.min.js:1:285412

THREE.WebGLRenderer: S3TC compressed textures not supported. three.min.js:1:285500

The use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Instead use the defaultPrevented. web.html
```

Do you think it could be related to not showing the correct colors?

Thank you very much! Regards.

Ruben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216355/ros3djs-set-urdf-color-not-working/) by [rubenvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22020/rubenvm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried switching your mesh loader?
https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs/issues/78

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubenvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22020/rubenvm/) on 2015-08-24**:
Thank you very much!! It was just the same problem!